# is there a formula to know how many enemies i can place before jumping character?

Tags: android, game-design, game-mechanics

My game is very similar to the hidden game in chromes web browser. I have a character that needs to jump over incoming enemies. Is there any way i can know when to send an incoming enemy? Some of the factors to take in to account i guess are the speed of enemies, height of jump, speed of jump, and dimensions of bitmaps (that represent character, and enemies).

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you're talking about an *infinite runner*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something as simple as this would give you the rough time the player will have to react if you were to spawn an enemy right now.

```
minReactionTime = 0.5; //Give the player half a second to react
closingSpeed = enemySpeed + playerSpeed;

if ( (enemySpawn - playerPosition) / closingSpeed >= minReactionTime )
{
   spawnEnemy();
}
```

Comment: looks good but can you explain in words what that is going to do?

Comment: Basically it just calculates how long it will take the player and enemy to collide if they continue moving forward at max speed.

This gives you a rough estimate of how long the player will have to react if you spawn an enemy at the "enemySpawn" point in that code.